# mysql select count distinct row amount

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to count rows in MySQL that have 5 or more rows with a certain value?

It would be the exact same as distinct but would ignore values that have less than 5 rows

Also if it does find a value with 5+ rows, I only want it to count as 1.

Please let me know if this is unclear or not clear enough

```
Table:
ID 
1001
1001
1001
1001
1001
1002
1002
1003
1003
1003
1003
1003
1004
```

I want for this table to count the amount of unique IDs that have 5 or more rows.
So I'd want this to return 2

UPDATE:

```
$var = 5;
try{

  $results = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM(
    SELECT user_id as YourCount
    FROM card_stats
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING count(*) >= ?)");

  $results->bindParam(1,$var);//value
  $results->execute();
  $hold = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
  exit();
}
var_dump($hold);
```

I tried the above but it gave me an error. Did I mess something up here?

UPDATE 2:
This worked for me

```
$var1 = 1101;
$var2 = 5;
try{

  $results = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*)
            FROM (SELECT user_id, count(*) as cnt
                  FROM card_stats
                  WHERE deck_id = ?
                  GROUP BY user_id
                 ) card_stats
            WHERE cnt >= ?;");

  $results->bindParam(1,$var1);//value
  $results->bindParam(2,$var2);//value
  $results->execute();
  $hold = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
  exit();
}
var_dump($hold);
```

Comment: You need to post table structure and values and expected output, plus what you've tried.

Comment: HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5?

Comment: Use `HAVING(COUNT(your_row)) >= 5` for those rows.

Comment: @artm okay, I'll update that now. Will only include the important areas. Haven't tried anything because I don't know if it's possible

Comment: @TrevorWood I've updated my question will work for you now

Comment: You may want to think about introducing a PRIMARY KEY,

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the heads up, In my actual DB there's a primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your clarified question, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select col, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by col
     ) t
where cnt >= 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

So something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalMoreThenFive FROM(
    SELECT value as YourCnt
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY value
    HAVING count(*) >= 5)
```

The having clause is to filter only those who have 5 or more rows, and then you wrap it with another query to count how many values like this are there.